# R: splitting a string between two characters using strsplit()

Tags: r, split, strsplit

Let's say I have the following string:

```
s <- "ID=MIMAT0027618;Alias=MIMAT0027618;Name=hsa-miR-6859-5p;Derives_from=MI0022705"
```

I would like to recover the strings between `";"` and `"="` to get the following output:

```
[1] "MIMAT0027618"  "MIMAT0027618"  "hsa-miR-6859-5p"  "MI0022705"
```

Can I use `strsplit()` with more than one split element?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**1) strsplit with matrix** Try this:

```
> matrix(strsplit(s, "[;=]")[[1]], 2)[2,]
[1] "MIMAT0027618"    "MIMAT0027618"    "hsa-miR-6859-5p" "MI0022705"
```

**2) strsplit with gsub** or this use of `strsplit` with `gsub`:

```
> strsplit(gsub("[^=;]+=", "", s), ";")[[1]]
[1] "MIMAT0027618"    "MIMAT0027618"    "hsa-miR-6859-5p" "MI0022705"
```

**3) strsplit with sub** or this use of `strsplit` with `sub`:

```
> sub(".*=", "", strsplit(s, ";")[[1]])
[1] "MIMAT0027618"    "MIMAT0027618"    "hsa-miR-6859-5p" "MI0022705"
```

**4) strapplyc** or this which extracts consecutive non-semicolons after equal signs:

```
> library(gsubfn)
> strapplyc(s, "=([^;]+)", simplify = unlist)
[1] "MIMAT0027618"    "MIMAT0027618"    "hsa-miR-6859-5p" "MI0022705"
```

ADDED additional `strplit` solutions.

Comment: Cool - base on this I found a way to extract the third element of the split `hsa-miR-something` for every line of a column inside a data frame using: `unlist(apply(B, MARGIN=1, FUN=function(x) matrix(strsplit(x[column number], "[;=]")[[1]], 2)[2,][3]))`

Comment: Note that the code in your comment simplifies to `matrix(strsplit(s, "[;=]")[[1]], 2)[2, 3]`

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I found the usage of lookaround regular expressions quite elegant for this problem:

```
library(stringr)
your_string <- '/this/file/name.txt'
result <- str_extract(string = your_string, pattern = "(?<=/)[^/]*(?=\\.)")
result
```

In words,

1. The `(?<=...)` part looks **before** the desired string for a`...` (in this case a forward slash).
2. The `[^/]*` then looks for as many characters in a row that are not a forward slash (in this case `name.txt`).
3. The `(?=...)` then looks after the desired string for a `...` (in this case the special period character, which needs to be escaped as `\\.`).

This also works on dataframes:

```
library(dplyr)
strings <- c('/this/file/name1.txt', 'tis/other/file/name2.csv')
df <- as.data.frame(strings) %>% 
  mutate(name = str_extract(string = strings, pattern = "(?<=/)[^/]*(?=\\.)"))
# Optional
names <- df %>% pull(name)
```

Or, in your case:

```
your_string <- "ID=MIMAT0027618;Alias=MIMAT0027618;Name=hsa-miR-6859-5p;Derives_from=MI0022705" 
result <- str_extract(string = your_string, pattern = "(?<=;Alias=)[^;]*(?=;)") 
result # Outputs 'MIMAT0027618'
```